# .Net Core Data Annotations - localization with shared resources

Tags: .net-core, localization, annotations

I would like to use shared resx file to specify all the translatable strings (both for translator convenience, and more importantly to avoid having dozens of separate resx files that clash with DRY principle). I got it working with IStringLocalizer for controllers and views, but I just can't figure out how to implement it for model's data annotations.

It works by using separate files like Models.AccountViewModels.LoginViewModel.en.resx, but how would I go and use shared resource file for data annotations instead of specific ones? Can anyone share example of implementation?

P.S. Environment is .NET Core 1.1 so both validation and display annotations should be in that version available for localization

Answer (score 9):

Step 1: Create a simple class, named ValidationMessages.cs and leave it empty. I will assume that your class is located in /Validation folder.

Step 2: Modify provider for data annotations localizer in your Startup.cs file to be like this:

```
mvcBuilder.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => 
{
    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => 
    {
        return factory.Create(typeof(ValidationMessages));
    };
});
```

Step 3: Create folder /Validation in /Resources (I assume that you are keeping all resource files in that folder) and then add ValidationMessages.fr-FR.resx file there (for French culture i.e.).

Step 4: Add entries to the resource files with keys of your liking. I assume that you will have keys like RequiredError, MaxLengthError, etc.

Step 5: Decorate properties on your model class with [Required(ErrorMessage="RequiredError")].

Next time property validation fails, validation messages will be pulled from ValidationMessages.{culture}.resx files.

Keep in mind though, that not only validation messages will be searched there, but also property names if you use DisplayAttribute.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense and doesn't even work. if you give to "ErrorMessage" property a string value it will display that.
Out of despair I tried it and doesn't work at ALL